# Counting how many times a base function is being used, Python

Tags: python, for-loop, counter, strip

I wanna be able to count how many times the strip function as well as how many white spaces are being removed  in a for loop:

reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['hi', 'thanks ', 'for ', 'helping '],
                   'more_words': ['i ', ' have', 'been', 'stuck'],
                   'even_more_words': ['four ', ' ages', 'word' , 'more words']})

count = 0 
# striping white spaces
for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()

print("I stripped this many blank spaces:", count)
```

The output should be 7, as it striped 7 white spaces

What is the simplest way to achieve this? 
Any hints or areas to look into would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong. Can you confirm that you are looking for the number of *spaces* removed (as in my answer), or the number of strings that changed? If the latter, Felipe's is the right answer.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm looking for number of spaces removed. Your solution is perfect - Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to store the original string length and then subtract the new length from it. The only mutation is the `strip` operation, so this should be correct.

```py
df = {'words': ['hi', 'thanks ', 'for ', 'helping '],
                   'more_words': ['i ', ' have', 'been', 'stuck'],
                   'even_more_words': ['four ', ' ages', 'word' , 'more words']}

count = 0 
# stripping white spaces
for col in df:
    count += sum(len(x) for x in df[col])
    df[col] = [x.strip() for x in df[col]]
    count -= sum(len(x) for x in df[col])
print("I stripped this many blank spaces:", count)
```

<sup>This a more minimal example, without having to use Pandas, but the idea is the same.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using .apply function you can strip and count all values in the same time using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['hi', 'thanks ', 'for ', ' helping '],
                   'more_words': ['i ', ' have', 'been', 'stuck'],
                   'even_more_words': ['four ', ' ages', 'word' , 'more words']})

count = 0 
# striping white spaces

def count_strip(string):
    global count

    striped_string = string.strip()
    count+= len(string) - len(striped_string)

    return striped_string

for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(count_strip)

print("I striped this many blank spaces:", count)
```

output

```sh
I striped this many blank spaces: 8
```

Comment: This only counts the number of *changes*, right? Not the actual number of spaces removed?

Comment: Yes, I can change for do that.

Comment: Hold on, I'll first ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: @usr2564301  I'm looking to count the number of spaces removed

Comment: Add that in your question "many times the strip function is being used" open for other interpretation.

Comment: @FelipeBorges Sorry for the confusion. I needed to know this too :) Thank you